# Agregar elementos a Tableview desde una lista en JavaFX

Tags: java, poo, javafx, listview, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo una lista de Java que tiene objetos de tipo película dentro de ella. Quiero poner los datos de las películas dentro de un TableView. Pero no he podido encontrar la manera.
Aquí está la clase que se encarga de todo eso.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
Scene scene;
Stage window;
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
FileChooser fs;
String linea ="";
String pelisD[];
String id,nombre,genero,anio,calif;
ListaDoble list = new ListaDoble();
FileReader archivolector;


@FXML 
private TextField txtdatosd;
@FXML
private Button btnAbrirD;  
@FXML
private Button btnaddD;
@FXML
private TextField txttdisponibles;
@FXML
private TableView<Peliculas> table;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Peliculas, String> idCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Peliculas, String> nombreCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Peliculas, String> generoCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Peliculas, String> anioCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Peliculas, String> califCol;
```

Aquí está mi ObservableList:

```
public ObservableList<Peliculas> lista = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
      new Peliculas(id, nombre, genero, anio, calif)
);
```

Aquí está el método que me permite abrir un archivo y obtener su ruta:

```
public void abrirD(ActionEvent e) throws IOException{
    File f=null;
    f=fs.showOpenDialog(window);
        if(f != null){
       txtdatosd.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());            
        }            
}
```

Aquí leo los archivos, los guardo en una lista y trato de mostrarlos en el TableView:

```
//Obtengo los datos de las pelicuas a través de un archivo CSV
public void leerArchivoCSVd(ActionEvent e) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
 // TODO code application logic here
    try {
        archivolector = new FileReader(String.valueOf(txtdatosd.getText()));
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(archivolector);
        while(buffer.ready()){
            if(!(linea = buffer.readLine()).equals("\000")){
                // System.out.println(linea);
                pelisD = linea.split(",");

                //aqui separo los campos de las peliculas
                id= pelisD[0].toString();
                nombre = pelisD[1].toString();
                genero = pelisD[2].toString();
                anio = pelisD[3].toString();
                calif = pelisD[4].toString();
                Peliculas peli = new Peliculas(id, nombre, genero, anio, calif);
                //aqui los agrego a una lista
                list.agregarAlFinal(peli);
                //Aqui trato de agregarlos al TableView
                lista.add(peli);

            }
            //en este txt me puedo dar cuenta de que las peliculas se agregaron a la lista porque obtengo el tamaño de la lista
             txttdisponibles.setText(String.valueOf(list.verTam()));    
        }



    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Aquí está mi escucha:

```
public void escucha(){
    fs=new FileChooser();
    btnAbrirD.setOnAction(evt ->{try {
        abrirD(evt);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

});
btnaddD.setOnAction(evt -> {try {
            leerArchivoCSVd(evt);
            } catch (IOException ex) {                Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);         }
}); }

Y por último aquí están los SetValue:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    escucha();
    idCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Peliculas, String>("idCol"));
    nombreCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Peliculas, String>("nombreCol"));
    generoCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Peliculas,String>("generoCol"));
    anioCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Peliculas,String>("anioCol"));
    califCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Peliculas, String>("califCol"));
    table.setItems(lista);
}
```

Al ejecutar el proyecto, abrir el archivo CSV leerlo y agregar los objetos a la lista, el TableView aparece así:

[image: Se puede ver como la lista si tiene elementos]

Ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

Debes inicializar correctamnente en el metodo initialize el observable array list.

En la declaracion:

```
@FXML
private ObservableList<FormatoDescripcion> lista;
```

y dentro del initilize.

```
lista = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Revisa eso. Otra acotación seria que generalmente la tabla no muestra los datos a pesar de estar porque las columnas no están inicializadas correctamente.